# 2D Spaceship Thruster Movement - Turning

Tags: unity, physics-engine

I have a spacecraft (shown in the image) built out of ‘blocks’ / 3D planes. It is drawn within a 3D space, but I’m ignoring the Y axis for now and keeping things on a “2D” XZ axis.

[image: Top-down view of spaceship]

The ship has a number of thruster blocks (represented in blue); each of which should fire depending on user input (does the user want to go forward? or turn left? etc).

Although the image doesn’t show it, each thruster is oriented in a logical direction; i.e the thrusters labelled A & E point left, B & F point right, thrusters G & H point down, thrusters C & D point up.

Thrusters are placed arbitrarily around the ship. There is no actual 'Thruster A' or 'Thruster B'; I'm just using the spacecraft in the above image as an example.

I already have the following which works for forward/backward thrust and strafing (in pseudo code):

```
foreach(thruster in ship.thrusters) {

    // Forward thrust
    if(keyPressed W) && thruster.direction == ShipLocalSOUTH) {

        thruster.fire();
    }

    // Backward thrust
    if(keyPressed S) && thruster.direction == ShipLocalNORTH) {

        thruster.fire();
    }

    // Strafe Left
    if(keyPressed Q) && thruster.direction == ShipLocalEAST) {

        thruster.fire();
    }

    // Strafe right
    if(keyPressed E) && thruster.direction == ShipLocalWEST) {

        thruster.fire();
    }

    // Turn left
    if(keyPressed A && ??) {

        // ??
    }

    // Turn right
    if(keyPressed D && ??) {

        //??
    }
}

class Thruster {

    private thrusterPower = 10;

    public void fire() {

        shipRigidbody.AddForceAtPosition (thruster.transform.forward * thrusterPower, thruster.transform.position);
    }
}
```

**My problem lies in determining which thrusters to fire to turn the ship.**

I’ve done a lot of googling on this and have found quite a lot of info already. I.e:

[Using Torque and Thrusters to Move and Rotate a Player-Designed Spaceship](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-torque-and-thrusters-to-move-and-rotate-a-player-designed-spaceship--gamedev-2610)

However my maths/trig skills are - to be blunt - crap and so I’m hoping to get a somewhat simpler explanation or even some code to help me understand and solve this problem. I'm not aiming for superbly accurate physics, just something that is fun to play.

Comment: You want to fire thrusters in pairs about the centre of mass. So to rotate clockwise A and F would fire. G and D together would also rotate clockwise

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more clear; thrusters can be placed arbitrarily about the spacecraft and in any number, there isn't actually a specific 'Thruster A' or 'Thruster B'. So while I myself understand which thrusters would need to fire in any given arrangement, I need my code to understand that too :)

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense! You can definately calculate what axis a thruster will cause rotation about. But with arbitrary trusters it will be very difficult to isolate rotation from translation. I think the axis is going to be the cross product of the thust vector and vector from the centre of mass to the thuster (the sign of the resulting vector determining which direction round the axis the rotation is). You could fire all thrusters whose rotation axes are close to the requested axes. Is this just for the graphics or will these engines have  a real effect.

Comment: Some of the tutorials I found on the net speak of using the cross product as you say. I've no idea how to implement that along with the 'IsKeyPressed(A)' check. This is for actually moving the GameObject, not just for graphics. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you need to do, is scan your created ship for thrusters, and then initialize each thruster based on its position relative to the ship.  You would assign them Properties that will determine what direction it will make your ship go (what button to assign the thruster to fire off to).

Comment: @Jon thanks - I understand what you say but I believe that still leaves a similar question: how do I determine which button(s) is/are assigned to each thruster? I suppose I could allow the player to manually assign keys to each thruster - that would work. However, I'd really prefer to have the game work out which thruster to fire rather than have the player do it manually.

Comment: Possibly allow the player to rotate the thruster

Comment: @Jon Yes, the player can already rotate the thruster when they place it. Let me give an example to try and define my problem further: To STRAFE left, thruster B and F would be fired. Easy, even for me. To ROTATE left, thruster B would be fired again, this time with thruster E. I guess turning left could also be achieved with C and H. So, its generally a combination of thrusters that achieve a turn. Therefore my game needs to work out an appropriate combination when the player wants to turn left or right (I already can do forwards / backwards / strafing).

Comment: There's definitely a way to do this automatically, in most cases. (Obviously if a ship lacks a thruster in a particular direction, you're out of luck) Are ships guaranteed to have thrusters in each cardinal direction? Are they guaranteed to be symmetric? (If not, you may need to allow thrusters to fire at different intensities to avoid undesired torque when driving forward/strafing). Also, is your center of mass fixed at some coordinate, or calculated dynamically from the ship build?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for your input. CoM is calculated for me by Unity's physics engine I believe. However, I am ensuring the 'center' of the GameObject is indeed the 'center' of the ship when I load it from file. So with appropriate thrusters, the ship would rotate more-or-less about its center. Ships are not guaranteed to have thrusters in each cardinal direction; if a player builds a ship that can't go forwards - that's up to them :D I don't mind about undesirable torque either; kind of even want it - I'd like to keep this as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the center, you have to find out if the thruster is above or below and left or right of your center.

```
public class Thruster : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform center;
public ThrusterType type;

public bool IsBelowCenterAxis {
    get {
        return transform.localPosition.z<center.localPosition.z;
    }
}

public bool IsLeftOfCenterAxis {
    get {
        return transform.localPosition.x<center.localPosition.x;
    }
}

public bool IsAboveCenterAxis {
    get {
        return transform.localPosition.z>center.localPosition.z;
    }
}

public bool IsRightOfCenterAxis {
    get {
        return transform.localPosition.x>center.localPosition.x;
    }
}

public void fire() {

}

}
```

and then :

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && 
            ((thruster.type == ThrusterType.LEFT && thruster.IsBelowCenterAxis) || 
             (thruster.type == ThrusterType.RIGHT && thruster.IsAboveCenterAxis) ||
             (thruster.type == ThrusterType.UP && thruster.IsLeftOfCenterAxis) ||
             (thruster.type == ThrusterType.DOWN && thruster.IsRightOfCenterAxis))) {

            thruster.fire();
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && 
           ((thruster.type == ThrusterType.RIGHT && thruster.IsBelowCenterAxis) || 
            (thruster.type == ThrusterType.LEFT && thruster.IsAboveCenterAxis) ||
            (thruster.type == ThrusterType.DOWN && thruster.IsLeftOfCenterAxis) ||
            (thruster.type == ThrusterType.UP && thruster.IsRightOfCenterAxis))) {

            thruster.fire();
        }
```

Now you just need to know the force with which to fire, but that's a different question.

Comment: I haven't seen this technique before but it works very well! I'll be editing my answer with updated code soon.

Comment: Glad it works for you, I also added an edit, as there was a little error with the center axis checks, just replace !IsBelowCenterAxis with IsAboveCenterAxis. The reason is, if center x or z equals thruster x or z (depending on rotation direction) there is no force pushing.