# Physics - Determine how much thrust to apply at each thruster for linear/angular acceleration

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, mathematics, box2d

I have a question somewhat similar to this one: [2D Spaceship Thruster Movement - Turning](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111897/2d-spaceship-thruster-movement-turning).

I have a ship with thrusters placed randomly on it (not necessarily symmetrically), and I need to know which thrusters and how much to fire them to have a perfectly linear acceleration, as well as how much they contribute to the angular acceleration of the ship to know which ones to fire when you want to turn the ship.

What I know: the position and orientation of the thrusters, the center of mass of the ship.

Basically I just need a way to make the ship obey the commands as best as physically possible, the commands being 'move' (apply acceleration on thrusters so if results in a linear acceleration), and 'rotate' (apply differential acceleration to maximize angular and minimize linear acceleration).

The game is 2D.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can think of this as a matrix multiply. You have an input vector which is the *amount of thrust* from each of the thrusters. You calculate how much acceleration each thruster provides (using mass, moment of inertia, center of mass, etc.). The output will be a vector of [linear x-axis, linear y-axis, angular] acceleration. The shape of all possible outputs is a 3-dimensional polyhedron. You're then looking for a point in that polyhedron intersected with constraint planes such as {angular=0} or {x=0}. Simplex algorithm can solve this but there are probably simpler ways too.

Comment: @amitp what an honor to have your comment! Your reputation really precedes you and your webpage is awesome! Thank you!
NauticalMile not exactly 100% because I want to actively counter side effect forces to achieve maximum control, but they certainly help 99% of the way.